Pytest to Locust
I want to use this pytest script as a performance test.
How can I implement i.e. Userclass and tasks given the following script?
With regards to scope, if I define a UserClass (i.e. FastHttpUser), could all the test be outside of this class?
import requests
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
import json
import pytest

# Arrange:
base_url = "https://example.com"

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
token = credential.get_token("api://xxx")
token = token.token

hpsId = ''
powerplantId = ''
all_pp_ids = []


def get_requests(t, endpoint):
    # Arrange:
    response = requests.get(f'{base_url}{endpoint}',
                    headers={"Authorization": f'Bearer {t}', 
   "Content-Type": 'application/json'})
    print(response.text)
    return response


def post_requests(t, endpoint, payload):
    # Arrange:
    data = payload
    json_data = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
    response = requests.post(f'{base_url}{endpoint}', data=json_data,
                     headers={"Authorization": f'Bearer {t}', 
   "Content-Type": 'application/json'})
   print(response.text)
   print(response.request.body)
   return response


def setpayload_bid_generate(hps_id):
    # Arrange:
    myjson = {"powerPlantIds": [hps_id]}
   return myjson


def setpayload_bids(hps_id, pp_id):
    # Arrange:
    myjson = {
        "hpsId": hps_id,
        "powerPlantId": pp_id,
        "readPeriod": [
            1713909600,
            1714089600
        ],
        "timeAxis": {
            "t0": 1713909600,
            "dt": 900,
            "n": 200
        }
    }
    return myjson


def setpayload_bids_generate_all(alle):
    # Arrange:
    myjson = {"powerPlantIds": alle}
    return myjson


def test_get_powerplant():
    global hpsId
    global powerplantId
    global all_pp_ids

    # Act:
    response = get_requests(token, '/mfrr- 
    eam/api/mfrr/eam/powerplant/all')
    try:
        data = response.json()
        all_pp_ids = [(item["powerPlant"]["id"]) for item in data]
        print("Alle powerplant IDs: ", all_pp_ids)
    except KeyError:
        print("Unable to get pp ids")

    try:
        hpsId = response.json()[0]["hpsId"]  # Get the hpsId
        print("HPS Ids: ", hpsId)
        print(response.text)
    except KeyError:
        print("Unable to get hpsID")
    try:
        powerplantId = response.json()[0]["powerPlant"]["id"]  
   # Get the powerplant id
        print("PP Ids: ", powerplantId)
    except KeyError:
       print("Unable to get powerplantId")
   # Assertion:
    assert response.status_code == 200  # Validation of status code


def test_bid_generate_for_powerplant():
   # Act:
   response = post_requests(token, '/mfrr- eam/api/mfrr/eam/bids/generate', 
   setpayload_bid_generate(hpsId))
  # Assertion:
  assert response.status_code == 200  # Validation of status code


def test_bids():
  # Act:
  response = post_requests(token, '/mfrr-eam/api/mfrr/eam/Bids', setpayload_bids(hpsId, 
  powerplantId))
  # Assertion:
  assert response.status_code == 200  # Validation of status code
    print("Responsen fra Bids: ", response.text)


 def test_bids_generate_all():
     # Act:
     response = post_requests(token, '/mfrr- 
     eam/api/mfrr/eam/bids/generate', 
     setpayload_bid_generate(all_pp_ids))
     # Assertion:
     assert response.status_code == 200  # Validation of status code

Shoudl every pytest-call be in a separate task? Or could it be all the test can be ran consecutively within the same task?
